# Cointegrated VAR impulse response function

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, impulse-response

I have two variables Consumption(c) and Earning(e).

According to the thesis,
c and e are cointegrated. So the author differences to two variables to be Diff_C and ct-et and get the stationary part. Then the author uses those 2 to depict the **Impulse response of the original c and e with VAR**

Here is the problem. What’s the method the author applies to get the impulse response of the original series? The difference in the original variables supposed to only predict the response of the difference.
How could the author get the impulse response of the original series through the above-transformed variables?

I would really appreciate it if someone can help. I have been bothered by this problem for a few months

**Update:**

According to the description below the figure, the impulse response generated from the difference through VAR depicts the value in level.

I am wondering how he estimated the IRF in level with VAR of difference instead of VECM?

[image: the figure attached in thesis]

Comment: If you know $\Delta y_{t+1}$ and the starting point $y_t$, you also know $y_{t+1}$: $y_{t+1}=y_t+\Delta y_{t+1}$. So as long as you know the starting point, you can work with differences without losing any information on the levels. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have tried VECM model. But I am wondering if the result is similar to the difference method the author apply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I can't understand why the series Δyt+1 can generate the impulse response of yt+1 with VAR. It's like some kind of recursive method?

Comment: If you know what happens to $\Delta y_{t+1}$ due to an impulse on time $t$, then you also know what happens to $y_{t+1}$, since there is a deterministic relationship $y_{t+1}=y_t+\Delta y_{t+1}$. You can look at either of them and learn about the other.

Comment: That’s informative, but the shock in Δ+1 would be more like a shock in differences than in levels, right?

Comment: Anyway I will try this one. That’s the light in the dark.